# JavaScript - Text won't change color when checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";

    var chk = document.querySelector('termsChkbx');

    document.getElementsByName("termsChkbx").onclick = function() {textCol()};

    function textCol() 
    {
        if(chk.checked){
             document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "black";
        }

    }

</script>
```

And this is the **html/php** that I'm trying to link it to.

```
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id="termsText">
    I agree to the terms and conditions
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx">
</p>
```

I need the color of the text to change to black when the checkbox is ticked and back to red when it isn't. I'm not sure where I am going wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any php...

Comment: There is no element with the ID `termsChkbox` and the `termsChkbx` selector doesn't match any element.

Comment: getElementsByName is a collection of elements. Try `document.getElementsByName("termsChkbx")[0].onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByName` instead.

```js
"use strict";

var chk = document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0];

document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0].onclick = function() {
  textCol()
};

function textCol() {
  if (chk.checked) {
    document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "black";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id="termsText">I agree to the terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
```

Comment: This is the exact funcitonality that I needed! I thought I had tried that, but I think I had gotten the syntax wrong somewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var chk = document.querySelector('input[name="termsChkbx"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet works for me. You were not passing the correct `id` to be selected.

```js
"use strict";

var chk = document.querySelector('#termsChkbx');

document.getElementById("termsChkbx").onclick = function() {textCol()};

function textCol() 
{
    if(chk.checked){
         document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "black";
    }else document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "red";

}
```

```html
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id="termsText">I agree to the terms and conditions
        <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx" id="termsChkbx"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector("#termsText input")` to be sure that the target is the input.

```
"use strict";

var chk = document.querySelector("#termsText input");

chk.onclick = function() {
  textCol()
};

function textCol() {
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("termsText");
  if (chk.checked) {
    paragraph.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    paragraph.style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider simplifying your code:

```js
document.querySelector('.trmsChkbx').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".trmsTxt").style.color = this.checked ? "#000" : "#f00";
}
```

```css
.trmsTxt{
    color: #f00; 
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<label class="trmsTxt" id="trmsTxt">
  I agree to the terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" name="trmsChkbx" class="trmsChkbx">
</label>
```